# How to call an Add Method in a Database Handler Class

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Hey so this is my first post but I am absolutely stuck. Either I don't understand database (which i really am kinda slapping this together to try and learn) I have created a basic CRUD DBHandlerclass with a method to add a plane. and a Activity that allows the user to input the info to save to the database.  I really appriciate any pointers, hints, or if you can show me a good tutorial. the tutorial that I used to build this database I found at http://mobilesiri.com/android-sqlite-database-tutorial-using-android-studio/

here is the DBHandler class.

```
   public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

//Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
//Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "avtoolsInfo";
//Plane info table name
private static final String TABLE_PLANES = "planeInfo";
// planes table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_TYPE = "type";
private static final String KEY_PLANE_CLASS = "plane_class";
private static final String KEY_FUEL_STYLE = "fuel_style";
private static final String KEY_NOTES = "notes";




public DBHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_PLANE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PLANES + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_TYPE + " TEXT," + KEY_PLANE_CLASS + " TEXT," + KEY_FUEL_STYLE + " TEXT," + KEY_NOTES + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_PLANE_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
    //Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PLANES);
    //Creating tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

// Adding a new plane
public void addPlane(PlaneInfo planeInfo)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, planeInfo.getName()); //plane name
    values.put(KEY_TYPE, planeInfo.getType()); //plane type
    values.put(KEY_PLANE_CLASS, planeInfo.getPlaneClass()); //plane class
    values.put(KEY_FUEL_STYLE, planeInfo.getFuelStyle());//plane fuel style
    values.put(KEY_NOTES, planeInfo.getNotes());//plane notes
// Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_PLANES, null, values);
// Closeing Database
    db.close();
```

Here is the activity to add.   [edit. this is the layout file]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="60dp">

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_layout_plane_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_plane_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/plane_name"
        android:maxLines="1" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_plane_type"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/input_layout_plane_name">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/plane_type"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/plane_type" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/plane_class_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/input_plane_type"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/plane_class_textview"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/plane_class_text"
        android:layout_below="@id/input_plane_type"
        ></Spinner>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fuel_style"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/spinner"
        android:text="@string/fueling_type_textview"/>
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_below="@id/spinner"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fuel_style"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    </Spinner>





    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/save_button"
        android:onClick="addPlane"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_plane_notes"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/spinner2"
        android:layout_above="@id/save_button">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/plane_notes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/plane_user_notes" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I really apriciate all the help.

[edit here is the add class]

```
    package com.example.jerem.avtools;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.graphics.drawable.DrawerArrowDrawable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AddNewPlane extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spinner spinner2;
    Spinner spinner;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_new_plane);
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.plane_class_spinner_data,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),parent.getItemAtPosition(position)+" is selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.fueling_styles,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Code looks okay so far. Where's the Activity where you are trying to add info to the database?

Comment: Another tutorial for you with easier to read code sections. https://guides.codepath.com/android/Local-Databases-with-SQLiteOpenHelper

Comment: oh sorry I guess i only added the layout... i will edit and add the class code. I just don't know where to go from here.

Comment: you might need to add: db = getWritableDatabase(); before calling execSQL()

Comment: I will read through that link... I think I have to somehow call the add method in a onClickListener from the add class i am just not sure how to do that. and also kinda confused on how to pass the data from class to db. I'm thinking maybe a shared prefrence variable but idk.

Comment: create an instance of DbHandler class. You will pass your ApplicationContext from your acitivty class for DbHandler constructor. Call the add method.

Comment: The spinner loads fine. I just cant figure out how to call the add method i made in the dbhandler

Comment: 'android:onClick="addPlane"' , you need to define this method in your activity. This addPlane is a method that will be called when you click that button. From this method inside your activity, call the addPlane method in DbHandler object  ( follow my above comment for that).

Comment: Jimmy thanks this is making my head hurt a little.  So if begin  my research on  how to make an instance of my dbhandler class. I should be able to make more progress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the spinners threw me for a loop. took a bit to figure them out but this is what i got thanks for your help guys.

```
public void addPlane(View view){
    PlaneInfo plane = new PlaneInfo();

    EditText editPlaneName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_plane_name);
    plane.setType(editPlaneName.getText().toString());

    EditText editPlaneType = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.plane_type);
    plane.setType(editPlaneType.getText().toString());

    Spinner spinnerPlaneClass = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    plane.setType(spinnerPlaneClass.getSelectedItem().toString());

    Spinner spinner1PlaneStyle = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    plane.setType(spinner1PlaneStyle.getSelectedItem().toString());

    EditText editPlaneNotes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.plane_notes);
    plane.setType(editPlaneNotes.getText().toString());

    dbHandler.addPlane(plane);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I feel like that link shows how to use that class... Anyways, here

```
public class AddNewPlane extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spinner spinner2;
    Spinner spinner;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2;

    DBHandler dbHandler; // add field

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_new_plane);

        dbHandler = new DbHandler(this); // initialize

  } 

    public void addPlane(View view) {
        PlaneInfo plane = new PlaneInfo();

        EditText edtPlaneType = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.plane_type);
        plane.setType(edtPlaneType.getText().toString());

        // TODO: Set more properties

        dbHandler.addPlane(plane);
    }
}
```

Regarding the `id` value, you should `return` the result of the insertion of the database handler. That will return the row number of the inserted record. You then can set the ID value on the `PlaneInfo` object from that.

Comment: Thanks cricket that gives me something to go off of

Comment: I missed the `addPlane` method of the XML that you'll need to add to the Activity

Comment: So I need to do something like such

Comment: public void addPlane(View view){
      PlaneInfo plane = new PlaneInfo();
                PlaneInfo planeInfo = new PlaneInfo();
                planeInfo.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                planeInfo.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                planeInfo.setType(cursor.getString(2));
                planeInfo.setPlaneClass(cursor.getString(3));
                planeInfo.setFuelStyle(cursor.getString(4));
                planeInfo.setNotes(cursor.getString(5));

Comment: Well, you don't need `plane = new PlaneInfo()` at all since you only want a single `PlaneInfo` object, but I don't think so since you are *adding* to the database, therefore, using a `cursor` to get information that does not yet exist doesn't make sense